# ls loose coupling can be achieved by any other manner rather than using parent class reference variable, in general not specifically in mine code?

Tags: java, loose-coupling, tightly-coupled-code

> Tight coupling is when a group of classes are highly dependent on one another.

```
class C {
    A a;

    C(B b) {
      a = b;
    }
}

Interface A {
}

class B implements A {
}
```

In my code I am accepting object of class through reference of class B not by parent interface A.

1. Is my code loosely or tightly coupled?

   > Loose coupling is achieved by means of a design that promotes
   >   single-responsibility and separation of concerns.
2. using the reference of parent class or interface make code more flexible to adopt any child class's object but how does it promotes single-responsibility.
3. Is loose coupling can be achieved by any other manner rather than using parent class reference variable, in any case not specifically in mine code?

Comment: Oh gosh, the formatting.

Comment: Why not read documentation first? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling

Comment: @chokdee i knew use the reference of parent is loose coupling as i did in my code, but when I am accepting the object it is by same class that why i was confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feels homeworky, but here is my answer.

The code is tightly coupled because the constructor for `C` depends upon `B` instead of the interface `A`. If you wanted to decouple `C` from `B`, you would accept an instance of `A` instead of `B`.

**Loosely Coupled Code**

```
class C {
    A a;

    C(A a) {
      this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't make the edit because it's too small, but the argument to C's constructor should be using the lowercase 'a' for the name.

Comment: Thanks guys. Fat fingered that.

Comment: as Sumit Singh says-Loose coupling is achieved by means of a design that promotes single-responsibility and separation of concerns.so my point is using the reference of parent class or interface make code more flexible to adopt any child class's object but how does it promotes single-responsibility.

Comment: @dubey-theHarcourtians I believe the answer lies in the way the question is phrased. Because it is asking specifically about the constructor  and accepting the implementation rather than the interface. Yes, it could still be tightly coupled, but this is certainly more loosely coupled.